# jQuery の jqXHR や Promise で成功の場合の結果を変形するには？

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

jqXHR や Promise が成功した場合に呼ばれる `done(fn)` の fn に渡される引数を、事前に変形できるでしょうか？

次のようなイメージです。

```
$.ajax(...)
    .???(function(originalResult) {
      // originalResult を変形して return
      return someTransform(originalResult);
    }).done(function(result) {
      // result には someTransform(originalResult) が渡される。
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) がある:

```
$.get("/")
.then(function(originalResult){
    return "OK";
})
.done(function(result){
    //result === "OK"
});
```

Comment: このサイト上で `$.get("/").then(function(originalResult) { return "OK"; }).done(function(result) { console.log(result === "OK"); });` を実行すると false と出るのでおかしいな、と思ったのですが、 jQuery のバージョンによって挙動が違うようですね。

Comment: 蛇足ですが `then(function() { })` の中で Deferred/Promise を返すと、その Deferred/Promise が解決された値が `done()` で取得できます。

`$.get('/')
.then(function(originalResult) {
  return $.get('/something', { id: originalResult });
})
.done(function(result) {
  // result は '/something' へのリクエストの結果
});`

Answer (score 2):

Promiseといえば、`.then()`がPromiseのもっとも重要なメソッドで、まさにkawtyさんが求めているものです。

`.then()`メソッドは関数を受け取り、その関数が返す値を代表するPromiseを返します。例えば、

```js
var d = $.Deferred();

d.promise().then(function (v) {
  snippet.log(v);                //　9
  return v * 2;
}).then(function (v2) {
  snippet.log(v2);               // 18
  return v2 + 7;
}).then(function (v3) {
  snippet.log(v3);               // 25
});

d.resolve(9);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

それだけではなくて、例え`.then()`へ渡す関数から別のPromiseを返しても、そのPromiseの中の値がちゃんと次の`.then()`に渡されます

```js
var d = $.Deferred();

d.promise().then(function (v) {
  snippet.log(v);
  return v * 2;
}).then(function (v2) {
  snippet.log(v2);

  var d2 = $.Deferred();
  d2.resolve(v2 + 7);
  return d2.promise();
}).then(function (v3) {
  snippet.log(v3);
});

d.resolve(9);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

ちなみに、このようなコードを書く必要はありません。

```
$.ajax(...)
.then(function(originalResult) {
  return someTransform(originalResult);
}).done(function(result) {
  // result には someTransform(originalResult) が渡される。
});
```

`.then()`に渡されている匿名関数はただ`originalResult`をそのまま`someTransform()`に渡しているので、この場合は`someTransform`を直接`.then()`に渡すことができるし、この方が読みやすいと思われることが多いです。

```
$.ajax(...)
.then(someTransform)
.done(function(result) {
  // result には someTransform(originalResult) が渡される。
});
```

そして最後に、jQueryのPromiseにはいくつかの問題点があり、[あまり使わない方がいい](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970)という人が多いです。jqXHRを扱っている場合、早く別のPromiseライブラリ又はJS6の`.when()`メソッドに渡して、ちゃんとしたPromiseに変換した方がいいです。

Answer (score 1):

ちょっと求められているのとは異なりますが、
以下のように wrapTransform() 関数を定義して、
done で呼び出すべき関数、をwrapTransform()の引数としてしまうという方法はどうでしょうか。

```
function wrapTransform(fn) {
  return function (originalResult) {
    return fn(someTransform(originalResult));
  }
}


$.ajax(...)
  .done(wrapTransform(function(result) {
    // result には someTransform(originalResult) が渡される。
  }));
```

Comment: 今回は Promise から Promise の変形をしたいのです。